# Why array print different-2 value using ,(comma) and .(period sign)?

Tags: perl

```
 my @arr = qw(12 5 78 56 1 785);
 my @new_arr = sort { $a <=> $b } @arr;
 print  @new_arr . "\n\n" ; #### print 6
 print  @new_arr , "\n\n" ; #### print value in short order
```

Hi,
 Could anyone tell me why it is printing different-2 value.

Thx,
Vijay

Comment: Seriously, learn the difference between scalar, and list contexts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one prints the concatenation of `@new_arr` with the string "\n\n".  That contatenation forces scalar context on `@new_arr`, hence it evaluates as its number of elements, in your case 6.

The second one evaluates all arguments to `print` in list context, hence `@new_arr` evaluates to the list of all its elements.

Comment: As it's the correct explanation, can I suggest you "accept" it by clicking the outline of a tick.  Users with low accept-ratios tend to get much less attention paid to their future questions.